# Atom linter-lintr cannot find lintr

Tags: r, atom-editor, lintr

I am using Atom for writing R code, and attempting to use lintr, but linter-lintr cannot find it. R is on my `$PATH` and `lintr` is installed in R.

Whenever I type, the following error happens.

```
/Users/bfh/.atom/packages/linter/lib/linter-registry.js:159 [Linter] Error running lintr Error: Error in library(lintr) : there is no package called 'lintr'
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages -> withCallingHandlers -> library
Execution halted
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/bfh/.atom/packages/linter-lintr/node_modules/sb-exec/lib/index.js:56:20)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)(anonymous function) @ /Users/bfh/.atom/packages/linter/lib/linter-registry.js:159
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling linter, linter-lintr, linter-minimap, and the relevant R packages. This setup is working fine on another computer.

Answer (score 2):

Start an R session in terminal or iterm2

`$ R`

and type:

`install.packages("lintr")`

https://atom.io/packages/linter-lintr